# nested xml into unordered list in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, html-lists

I am trying to convert a nested xml document to an unordered list using jquery.The xml document is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Parent>
    <name>Director</name>
    <Children>Exe Director1</Children>
    <Children>Exe Director2</Children>
    <Parent>
        <name>Exe Director3</name>
        <Children>Sub Director 1</Children>
        <Children>Sub Director 2</Children>
        <Parent>
            <name>Sub Director 3</name>
            <Children>Cameraman 1</Children>
            <Children>Cameraman 2</Children>
        </Parent>
    </Parent>    
</Parent>
```

The expected output:

```
 <ul>
    <li>Director
        <ul>
            <li>Exe Director 1</li>
            <li>Exe Director 2</li>
            <li>Exe Director 3
                <ul>
                    <li>Sub Director 1</li>
                    <li>Sub Director 2</li>
                    <li>Sub Director 3
                        <ul>
                            <li>Cameraman 1</li>
                            <li>Cameraman 2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The output which I am getting.

```
 <ul>
        <li>Director</li>
        <ul>
            <li>Exe Director1</li>
            <li>Exe Director2</li>
            <li>Exe Director3</li>
            <ul>
                <li>Sub Director 1</li>
                <li>Sub Director 2</li>
                <li>Sub Director 3</li>
                <ul>
                    <li>Cameraman 1</li>
                    <li>Cameraman 2</li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </ul>
```

As you can see,the Children are not getting created inside the parent `li` but outside it
The latest version of the code

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var levels;
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "test.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function (xml) { 
                var $ul = xmlParser(xml, $('#ListContainer'));
            }
        });
    });

    function xmlParser(xml,ul) {
        $(xml).contents().each(function (i, el) 
        {
            if (el.nodeName.toUpperCase() == "CHILDREN") 
            {
               $("<li>").text($(el).text()).appendTo($('ul:last')); // Append <li> Children
            } else if (el.nodeName.toUpperCase() == "NAME") 
            {
                $('<li>').text($(el).text()).appendTo(ul);
                $('<ul>').insertAfter($("li:last"));
            }
            else if (el.nodeName.toUpperCase() == "PARENT") 
            {
               if($('ul').length == 0)
                {
                    ul = ul.append('<ul>');
                }
                ul.append(xmlParser($(el),$("ul:last") )); // Recursively append the other Parent
            }
        });
        return ul;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="ListContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am breaking my head over this code.Can you guys help me out with what might be going wrong!

Thanks

Comment: move `$("#ListContainer").append($ul);` out of recursion

Comment: @rt2800 Do I need to place a check when the xml is emptied , call a function from there and write the append code in that function

Comment: create `<UL>` outside `xmlParser()` method and pass it as parentElem. e.g. `var $ul = xmlParser(xml, $('<ul>')); $("#ListContainer").append($ul)` in success callback of $.ajax. Return $ul as output result of xmlParser() function

Comment: If you could post your comment as an answer,I could give the "accept"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending PARENT element to same "ul" element for all "PARENT" contents. use

```
$ul.find('li').last().append(xmlParser($(el)));
```

instead of

```
$ul.append(xmlParser($(el)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are appending PARENT element to same "ul" element for all "PARENT" contents. use

```
 $ul.find('li').last().append(xmlParser($(el)));
```

instead of

```
 $ul.append(xmlParser($(el)));
```

refer below link for last api:

http://api.jquery.com/last/

Comment: tried that.Still gives the same result.Also,how can I move `$("#ListContainer").append($ul);` out of recursion

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use jQuery's map function recursively, as in the following example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var map = function() {
            if ($(this).is("parent")) {
                var children = $(this).children().map(map).get().join('');
                $(this).children().remove();
                var result = "<li>" + $(this).text();
                return result + "<ul>" + children + "</ul></li>";
            }

            if ($(this).is("Children")) {
                return "<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>";
            }
        };

    $.get("test.xml", function(data) {
        var result = $(data).map(map);
        $("div").html("<ul>" + result[0] + "</ul>");
    }, "html");
}); 
</script>
```

This ensures that the input tree is traversed completely, and that the resulting output has the same "indentations" as the input.

Notice that `map()` returns an array, so the resulting string is present as the first item of the array.

Comment: This removes the parent names from the list and prints only the child nodes?
Please take a look at the xml code,the expected output and the generated output.

Comment: Apologies. I amended the code, which should create the desired structure now.

Comment: The list is generated just fine,the only issue being that the parent's name is not coming inside the list!

Answer (score 1):

Here is Consolidation of my comments into a coherent answer-->

1. move `$("#ListContainer").append($ul);` out of recursion;
2. create `<UL>` outside `xmlParser()` method and pass it as parentElem. 
   e.g. `var $ul = xmlParser(xml, $('<ul>')); $("#ListContainer").append($ul)` (in success callback of $.ajax)
3. Return `$ul` as output result of `xmlParser()` function

Comment: Thanks for your help rt2800. Unfortunately , SO doesn't allow a user to accept more than one answer.Thanks again!